# How to plot dark green graph with RGB indication

Tags: matlab, plot, colors, rgb, linestyle

I want to plot a dark green and a dark green dashed graph, but unfortunately MatLab complains that the vector does not have the same length

> Error using plot
>
> Vectors must be the same length.
>
> Error in EasySim (line 174) `

```
plot(x,z1,'b--',x,z2,'c--',x,z3,'b',x,z4,'c',x,z5,'g',x,z6,'g--',x,z7,'color',[0 0.5 0],x,z8,'color',[0 0.5 0],'linestyle','--')
```

Comment: You should add the matlab tag, and add some example data to make a reproducible example

Comment: Read what a [mcve] is, and include one. Note that it must be **minimal**, so no need of 8 variables, and **complete**, we should able to copy paste it and run it

Comment: But my Question is why [0 0.5 0] doesnt fit?

Comment: The problem is probably that one of your vectors you're trying to plot has a different length. This doesn't have anything to do with the colours.

Comment: But if i choose colours like 'b--' etc. my code works. Also the error is for the line of the plot

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have more then one 'color', [R G B] in one plot statement.

so your code is like you write:

```
plot(x,z1,'b--',x,z2,'c--',x,z3,'b',x,z4,'c',x,z5,'g',x,z6,'g--',x,z7,'color',[0 0.5 0],x,z8,[0 0.5 0],'linestyle','--')
```

so the last line is x,z8,[0 0.5 0]. because x and z8 is not in length of 3 you got this error.

Note: if x and z8 is 3 elements each you got different error: Data must be a single matrix Y or a list of pairs X,Y.

you can check it on this example:

```
x=1:5
z1=x.^2;
z2=x.^3;
z3=x.^4;
z4=x.^5;
z5=x.^6;
z6=x.^7;
z7=x.^8;
z8=x.^9;
```

change x to x=1:3 to see what happen in this case

Answer (score 1):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49132510/5358968):

> You cannot have more then one 'color', [R G B] in one plot statement.

You can change the colors after you've plotted them:

```
x = 0:4;
h = plot(x, x, '-', x, x.^2, '--');
set(h(1), 'color', [1 0 1])
set(h(2), 'color', [0 0.5 0])
```